# JAXB and Inheritance with external custom bindings

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, nested, polymorphism

I'm currently trying to model the [Spring LDAP Filters](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/basic.html#basic-filters) in my XML schema.  This involves polymorphic types, which can be arbitrarily nested:

```xml
<andFilter>
  <notFilter>
     <equalsFilter name="mail" value="asfd@example.com" />
  </notFilter>
  <likeFilter name="mail" value="asdf*" />
</andFilter>
```

This is how I'm defining the above filters in my xsd (I actually have some intermediate abstract types defined, but left them out for simplicity):

```xml
<xsd:complexType name="baseFilterType" abstract="true" />
<xsd:element name="filter" type="tns:baseFilterType" />

<xsd:complexType name="andFilterType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="tns:filter" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="andFilter" type="tns:andFilterType" substitutionGroup="tns:filter" />

<xsd:complexType name="notFilterType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="tns:filter" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="notFilter" type="tns:notFilterType" substitutionGroup="tns:filter" />

<xsd:complexType name="likeFilterType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="tns:attributeName" />
    <xsd:element ref="tns:value" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="likeFilter" type="tns:likeFilterType" substitutionGroup="tns:filter" />

<xsd:complexType name="equalsFilterType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="tns:attributeName" />
    <xsd:element ref="tns:value" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="equalsFilter" type="tns:equalsFilterType" substitutionGroup="tns:filter" />
```

I've extended each of the filter classes with some custom behavior (to implement the visitor pattern), but I can't figure out how to have JAXB bind to those instead of `JAXBElement<? extends BaseFilterType>` that's used throughout the generated classes.

The JAXB model classes are generated at build time, and so I can't modify them directly -- **I must use external custom bindings for any customizations**.  I've tried the `implClass` and `baseClass` customizations but haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Can anyone help?

**Edit:** I'm using Spring's `Jaxb2Marshaller` with `contextPaths` set for marshalling and unmarshalling.  I expected this to utilize `ObjectFactory` for object instantiation, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

**Edit 2:** The filter elements are referenced by the top-level element as well as by each other, like:

```xml
<xsd:element name="GetAttributesRequest">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="filter:filter" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

So, the `GetAttributesRequest` object will be marked with `@XmlRootElement` while the filter classes themselves will not be.  However, even the top-level `GetAttributesRequest` object isn't being instantiated by `ObjectFactory`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit :**

Solution used by question author :

> I ended up using JAXB binding customizations to make the ObjectFactory
>   produce instances of my classes, and then set the
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.ObjectFactory (note the internal)
>   unmarshaller property on Spring's Jaxb2Marshaller to force it to use
>   the factory.

---

**Original answer :**

Yes, it's possible to add behaviors to the generated classes. You want to have a look at **[the related documentation](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Adding_behaviors.html)**

Here's a simple example from the documentation :

**JAXB Generated Code**

```
package org.acme.foo;

@XmlRootElement
class Person {
  private String name;

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String) { this.name=name; }
}

@XmlRegistry
class ObjectFactory {
  Person createPerson() { ... }
}
```

**Extended class**

package org.acme.foo.impl;

```
class PersonEx extends Person {
  @Override
  public void setName(String name) {
    if(name.length()<3) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    super.setName(name);
  }
}

@XmlRegistry
class ObjectFactoryEx extends ObjectFactory {
  @Override
  Person createPerson() {
    return new PersonEx();
  }
}
```

**Example of Unmarshalling**

```
Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
u.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.ObjectFactory",new ObjectFactoryEx());
PersonEx p = (PersonEx)u.unmarshal(new StringReader("<person />"));
```

More info [here](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Adding_behaviors.html)

Comment: I tried this already actually, but for whatever reason none of any of the `ObjectFactory`'s constructors are ever invoked.  I'm using `Jaxb2Marshaller` with `contextPaths` set, which should use the `ObjectFactory` from what I understand.

Comment: I ended up using JAXB binding customizations to make the `ObjectFactory` produce instances of my classes, and then set the `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.ObjectFactory` (note the `internal`) unmarshaller property on Spring's `Jaxb2Marshaller` to force it to use the factory.  I'm checking your answer as correct since it ultimately led me to the correct solution.

Comment: I add your comment in my answer.